# Edit text integer

Tags: android, eclipse, integer

Android application is not work, application has stopped unfortunately. Where is wrong code?

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    final TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final int valueint = Integer.parseInt(edittext1.getText().toString());

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

           tw.setText(Integer.toString(20*valueint));
        }
    });


}
```

Is code true?

```
int valueint = Integer.parseInt(edittext1.getText().toString());
```

Comment: [Integer.parseInt()][1] method may throw an exception if the given string is not a parseable integer. You should check the LogCat output to see where the exception happens and debug through to see the cause.


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: Do you have any default value for editText? If editText is empty your app will crash when trying to parse it.

Comment: i cut paste int valueint = Integer.parseInt(edittext1.getText().toString())
in button clicked code
now working

Comment: If there's nothing written in the EditText, it would crash. You should have a check before executing this line.

Comment: Now, application working
but i clicking button when edittext was empty, app has stopped unfortunately

Comment: instead of `tw.setText(Integer.toString(20*valueint));` try `tw.setText(String.valueOf(20*valueint));` Another problem if you have empty value for int, you will have error like this. Check int before any other actions.

Comment: @Dudeist still app has stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use empty int value on create. It can work with some numbers in EditText, but when empty it must crash. Also tw.setText metod was wrong. Try this code, working:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

    EditText edit;// = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button button;// = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView tw;// = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int valueint;// = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);

        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                valueint = Integer.parseInt(edit.getText().toString());
                tw.setText(String.valueOf(20 * valueint));
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: you should add also some method to check for empty/null integer onClick.